# Problem while saving new objects

Tags: geopackage, qfield

When I create new objects in QField (3.1.6, they cannot be saved. A error message says "Unable to save changes" (in german: "Speichern nicht möglich" with a red dot beside.

Creating new objects of this layer (GeoPackge) on the pc (QGIS) works without any problems.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide details of your set up, e.g attribute settings, relations etc